# Filter Excel data based on date range selection on pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to know how to filter Excel data based of a specific date range using pandas via python.

For an example:

(sheet1.xlsx) contains:

```
DATE        51      52      53      54      55      56
20110706    28.52   27.52   26.52   25.52   24.52   23.52
20110707    28.97   27.97   26.97   25.97   24.97   23.97
20110708    28.52   27.52   26.52   25.52   24.52   23.52
20110709    28.97   27.97   26.97   25.97   24.97   23.97
20110710    30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
20110711    32.93   31.93   30.93   29.93   28.93   27.93
20110712    35.54   34.54   33.54   32.54   31.54   30.54
20110713    33.02   32.02   31.02   30.02   29.02   28.02
20110730    35.99   34.99   33.99   32.99   31.99   30.99
20110731    30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
20110801    32.48   31.48   30.48   29.48   28.48   27.48
20110802    31.04   30.04   29.04   28.04   27.04   26.04
20110803    32.03   31.03   30.03   29.03   28.03   27.03
20110804    34.01   33.01   32.01   31.01   30.01   29.01
20110805    27.44   26.44   25.44   24.44   23.44   22.44
20110806    32.48   31.48   30.48   29.48   28.48   27.48
```

If I want to filter this data from the range 20110708-20110803
The result would be:

```
DATE        51      52      53      54      55      56
20110708    28.52   27.52   26.52   25.52   24.52   23.52
20110709    28.97   27.97   26.97   25.97   24.97   23.97
20110710    30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
20110711    32.93   31.93   30.93   29.93   28.93   27.93
20110712    35.54   34.54   33.54   32.54   31.54   30.54
20110713    33.02   32.02   31.02   30.02   29.02   28.02
20110730    35.99   34.99   33.99   32.99   31.99   30.99
20110731    30.5    29.5    28.5    27.5    26.5    25.5
20110801    32.48   31.48   30.48   29.48   28.48   27.48
20110802    31.04   30.04   29.04   28.04   27.04   26.04
20110803    32.03   31.03   30.03   29.03   28.03   27.03
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to do this in excel or pandas? Does it matter which?

Comment: @EdChum, Pandas , I want this to be automatically calculated with pandas, without touching excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set DATE as an index from your Dataframe df (`df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)`).
You can then use loc to slice your DataFrame :

```
 df.loc[20110708:20110803]
```

You should find example here : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

PS : I assumed that the dtype of your index (DATE column) was int64.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather keep DATE as a standard column (not your index), you can also do this:

`df = df[(20110708 <= df.DATE) & (df.DATE <= 20110803)]`

The indexing isn't quite as pretty and it'll be a little slower, but it works on columns.

This is assuming you've already read the excel file in using `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`